# set linear layout elements spacing dynamically android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, param

I am creating a layout dynamically, I am using

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);             
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

to place my elements one below the other. But for my header, i am using a new layout

```
LinearLayout layout_header = new LinearLayout(this);             
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

and adding this in the view of the LinearLayout layout. But in LinearLayout layout_header, i have two buttons and i want one of them to be in total left and the other in total right. But both are coming side by side, i tried to include padding/margins but didn work.

I also created a layout params for both the buttons and tried adding margins/gravity/padding individually, but still did not work.

Please help how to proceed to place these buttons at two separate corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one thing at the far left and one at the far right, its easier to use a relative layout.  Just make the first `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and the other `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

Comment: thanks, but can we set this programatically?? i am generating the view by code, relative layout is fine for me!

Comment: Yes, you'd have to put it in a RelativeLayout and use the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams class to specify the constraints above.  Just add the right rule to the params for each.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Gabe's answer, since that's precisely what `RelativeLayout`s are for. However, if you want to keep it a `LinearLayout` for whatever reason, you can place an invisible `View` *between* your two `Button`s:

```
<Button
    ... />
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
    ... />
```

The `layout_weight` attribute specifies that it should take up the remaining room. Just be sure to use `0dp` for the width, so that doesn't interfere.